# Review questions with related tags only

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

Forgive me if I've missed this question. I tried searching for it with relevant terms, but got no results.

How about reviewing questions only with tags that are not marked as "ignored" (only "interesting" & with unmatched tags). This way it'd be better for reviewers to review the questions of their area of expertise, since at the moment I'm spending quite some time finding questions with relevant tags.