# Favourite Tags should show up on the /review section of Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, review, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please allow tag filtering on the new review pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72420/please-allow-tag-filtering-on-the-new-review-pages)
>   [Review questions with related tags only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112728/review-questions-with-related-tags-only)

In /questions, I have handy access to my favourite tags near the top, like so:

```
Favorite Tags
java ruby ruby-on-rails
```

I feel I should have my favourite tags next to me when reviewing posts, old, new, or otherwise since I still need to filter by my area of expertise.

Comment: *"since I still need my area of expertise"* Erm, what? Do you mean that you *forget* which things you know?

Comment: No, but it is useful to filter the questions easily. I find clicking on my favourites to be the fastest way to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Review questions with related tags only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112728/review-questions-with-related-tags-only), [Please allow tag filtering on the new review pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72420/please-allow-tag-filtering-on-the-new-review-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm, I'm not sure what you're talking about, as this is already listed in the review panel below the Tag Summary... Can you not find it?

[image: Favorite Tags in Review Panel]

Comment: I didn't notice it right at the bottom.
In that case, my request should be "favourite tags should be at the top."