# Allow reviewer to review only questions related to reviewers' activity

Tags: feature-request, review

As described also in these two other questions:

[- More aggressive tag match between reviewed question and reviewer activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143854/215829)

[- Review questions with related tags only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112728/215829)

The review quality is strongly related to the capability of the reviewer to understand the post. Wouldn't it be valid to allow revision only for posts related to the reviewers' experience?

This could be measured for example using how many points were earned for each tag and so forth...

Comment: One issue with this is that some edits are obviously wrong or correct so it just delays the time in which they are rejected/approved as they have to wait for someone with "experience" in the area to hit the review queue. Also at some point you have to draw the line because if it is a new tag very few may have the "experience".

Comment: No, it would not. And how do you rate people's experience? I'll let you in on a secret: Their score in a tag does *not* give you that information. Also, almost none of the review tasks require technical knowledge of the topic. The only exception (sometimes) is "exact duplicates".

Comment: An example: I work with PHP a lot, I think I'm pretty good at it (especially judging by the questions/answers I often see!), yet I **<strike>** don't think I've ever answered a PHP question **</strike>** have answered very few PHP questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I see 22 answers from you for PHP http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A237838+[php]

Comment: @FDinoff Wow; that's surprising! Cool. (You'd think I could have done that search before making the above claim! hehe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vast majority of review actions don't require knowledge of the subject material discussed in the post.  Only a handful of such posts require domain knowledge.

Restricting users to reviewing content that they have actively contributed to would dramatically limit the number of valid and appropriate reviews that they can make, while removing only a small number of posts that they shouldn't be reviewing.

As such, adding this restriction would cause more harm than it would help.

An entirely different "feature" is to simply apply a preference to tags that the reviewer is active in, without actually *requiring* them to be active in the related tags to review the post.  Note that that feature has existed since the review system was revamped last year.  You're much more likely to be shown posts in tags your active in, if there are any.  When you're shown posts from other tags it's generally because there are no posts from tags you *are* active in.  (Note that this is dependent on the queue, some I think don't have this feature, some do.)